# Unreal Engine not recognizing game mode, any ideas why?

Tags: unreal-engine4

So basically I created the game mode, have set up my char and what not. In that game mode I made it so that I was using said char. Here is how it looks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJJIa.png)

Now, when I click play, I don't actually get to posses the character. What happens is that I am still an observer, as if I didn't apply all those things in the settings. I can roam around at camera speed, but I don't get to control the char. Now if I press "Posses" I posses the character. The problem is is that nothing happens, like I have also added the movement and I still can't move, can't do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added a PlayerStart Actor to the Level?

Comment: Check to make sure that you also havent enabled `bDelayedStart` in the GameMode.